# Interface and Abstract in java and in android

Tags: java, android

I confused about abstract and Interface when I got that a class named Context is an Interface in java and the same class abstract in android why it is so? Please tell me.I know that both class are not same but my concern about Interface and Abstract class.

Comment: _"...the same class abstract in android..."_ - but it's not the same class, they have absolutely nothing to do with each other except for the name.

Comment: If you know they are not the same (`javax.naming.Context` and `android.content.Context`), why are you then insisting on comparing apples and oranges?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different classes that have the same name, in Java SDK [`Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html) is a name-object binding interface, and in Android [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is an abstract class that provides global information about the application environment.